# JUnit Parameterized from Excel file

Tags: java, excel, junit, parameterized

I'm trying to write a unit test importing data from an Excel file. A single row in the Excel would be a pojo for me. So I should execute the test for each single pojo:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TestClass {

private List<Payload> payloads;

@Parameterized.Parameters
public static List<Payload> loadData() throws IOException {
    ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream stream = classloader.getResourceAsStream("test-data/myExcel.xlsx");
    return new ExcelData(stream).getData();
}

public TestClass(List<Payload> payloads) {
    this.payloads = payloads;
}

@Test
public void check() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(payloads);
}
}
```

If I execute this test I get "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch" error.

Is there a way to execute the test for each of these pojos?

Comment: IMHO  the constructor should have just Payload as argument and field should be Payload type not List<Payload>

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. First time I use Parameterized and I got a bit confused. Thanks a lot!